# How can I change the memory allocator in a Linux 3.6.6 server to SLOB?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to use the SLOB allocator on my Linux kernel. I can not find any resources online.

Comment: Did my answer helped you or is there something still unclear? If it helped, you can mark it as "Accepted" to avoid duplicate questions on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turn on [`CONFIG_SLOB`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/SLOB.html) while [kernel configuration](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-2.4-HOWTO/kconfig.html) instead of `CONFIG_SLAB` or `CONFIG_SLUB`.

Read more: [1](https://lwn.net/Articles/157944/), [2](https://www.programmersought.com/article/11795979942/)